# creating a login more securely in phpmysql how other than mysql real escape?

Tags: php, mysql

i got a login script from net which i uses in my website for login application.its working fine but i want to make it more secure.Can you tell me what are the ways to secure a login other than mysql real escape.can you also tell me what will be the loop holes in a login where hackers can attack.i am some what good in phpmysql

Answer (score 1):

You can use prepared statements/PDO to ensure that no malicious queries can be injected into your code.

Links:

- [PDO::Prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)
- [PDOStatement::Execute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

You should still validate your inputs with [regex](http://regular-expressions.info) so your users can't just make whatever they want as their username. Say for example, I make my username `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malicioussite.com/bad.js"></script>`. I could then run my evil code on all your pages with my username, unless you sanitized either input or output.

Answer (score 0):

Leverage what the most exposed sites have learned. Copy WordPress or one of the other major sites where you can download their source code. This is not a wheel you want to reinvent.